# Point-free lens creation does not type check

Tags: haskell, pointfree, haskell-lens

In the function `test`, I traverse over a list, generate lenses from it's members, and then print some data. This works when I use a pointful call style. It fails to typecheck when I make it point-free.

Why is this the case, and how can I solve this problem?

It looks like to me that GHC is not retaining the information that the higher-ranked `f` (in the lens) is a `Functor` when using point-free style, but I'm not too sure.

I'm using GHC 7.8.3

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

type PlayerHandle = String

data Player = Player { _playerHandle :: PlayerHandle }
makeLenses ''Player

data GameState = GameState { _gamePlayers :: [Player] }
makeLenses ''GameState

type PlayerLens = Lens' GameState Player

getPlayerLens :: PlayerHandle -> PlayerLens
getPlayerLens handle f st = fmap put' get'
    where
        players = st^.gamePlayers
        put' player = let
            g p = case p^.playerHandle == handle of
                True -> player
                False -> p
            in set gamePlayers (map g players) st
        get' = f $ fromJust $ find (\p -> p^.playerHandle == handle) players


printHandle :: GameState -> PlayerLens -> IO ()
printHandle st playerLens = do
    let player = st^.playerLens
    print $ player^.playerHandle


test :: GameState -> IO ()
test st = do
    let handles = toListOf (gamePlayers.traversed.playerHandle) st
    --
    -- Works: Pointful
    --forM_ handles $ \handle -> printHandle st $ getPlayerLens handle
    --
    -- Does not work: Point-free
    forM_ handles $ printHandle st . getPlayerLens


main :: IO ()
main = test $ GameState [Player "Bob", Player "Joe"]
```

---

```
Test.hs:45:38:
    Couldn't match type `(Player -> f0 Player)
                         -> GameState -> f0 GameState'
                  with `forall (f :: * -> *).
                        Functor f =>
                        (Player -> f Player) -> GameState -> f GameState'
    Expected type: PlayerHandle -> PlayerLens
      Actual type: PlayerHandle
                   -> (Player -> f0 Player) -> GameState -> f0 GameState
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `getPlayerLens'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `printHandle st . getPlayerLens'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: I don't know the details, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with higher ranked types causing some typing issues. Passing `Lens` arguments can cause that sort of issue. It will probably work if you use `ALens` instead of `Lens`, since that is designed to be passed around.

Comment: @DavidYoung You *can* do it with `ALens`, but then the called function has to explicitly `cloneLens` it back to a normal lens before using it. That's normally only appropriate for a function that really needs the full lens features of its argument.

Comment: @DavidYoung: I'll have to look into it. A quick google didn't give rise to any tutorials/examples for `ALens` over `Lens`, but I should be able to figure it out. Time to call the day quits for now.

Comment: @DavidYoung After a while I realized that `ALens` is better for lenses than my alternative `newtype` hack, if one insists on having a consistent type, so I've now included them in my answer too. (I think it's still more "idiomatic lens" to use specific types at the usage sites.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Lens'` is a higher ranked type, and type inference is very brittle with those, and basically only works when all functions that take higher-rank arguments have explicit signatures to do so.  This works very badly with point-free code using `.` and the like, which don't have such signatures. (Only `$` has a special hack to sometimes work with this.)

The `lens` library itself gets around this by making sure that all functions that *use* a lens argument don't have a fully general lens type for it, but only a type which indicates the precise lens feature they *use*.

In your case, it's the `printHandle` function which is the culprit for this.  Your code will compile if you change its signature to the more precise

```
printHandle :: s -> Getting Player s Player -> IO ()
```

I found this signature by deleting the original one and using `:t printHandle`.

EDIT (and EDIT again to add `ALens'`): If you think the "cure is worse than the illness", then depending on your needs another option, which doesn't require you to change your function signatures, but which *does* require you to do some explicit conversion, is to use the `ALens'` type instead.  You then need to change two lines:

```
type PlayerLens = ALens' GameState Player
...
printHandle st playerLens = do
    let player = st^.cloneLens playerLens
...
```

`ALens'` is a non-higher rank type that has been cleverly constructed so that it contains all the information needed to extract a general lens from it with `cloneLens`.  But it still *is* a special subtype of a lens (the `Functor` has just been particularly cleverly chosen) so you only need explicit conversion *from* `ALens'` to `Lens'`, not the other way.

A third option, which may not be the best for lenses, but which usually works for higher-rank types in *general*, is to turn your `PlayerLens` into a `newtype`:

```
newtype PlayerLens = PL (Lens' GameState Player)
```

Of course this now needs both wrapping and unwrapping in several places in your code. `getPlayerLens` was particularly disrupted:

```
getPlayerLens :: PlayerHandle -> PlayerLens
getPlayerLens handle = PL playerLens
    where
        playerLens f st = fmap put' get'
            where
                players = st^.gamePlayers
                put' player = let
                    g p = case p^.playerHandle == handle of
                        True -> player
                        False -> p
                    in set gamePlayers (map g players) st
                get' = f $ fromJust $ find (\p -> p^.playerHandle == handle) players
```

Comment: A case where the cure might be worse than the illness. Oh well, but thanks for the info!