# Why does this lens function require a type signature?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm writing a function which uses the lenses library, but curiously, the code doesn't compile when I remove the type annotation.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, Rank2Types #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State

import Data.List (elemIndex)

data MyRecord = MyRecord { _someField :: [Int], _anotherField :: [String] }
makeLenses ''MyRecord

updateRecord :: Eq a => a -> Lens' b [a] -> (Int -> c) -> State b c
updateRecord elem lens f = do field <- view lens <$> get
                              case elemIndex elem field of
                                Just index -> return $ f index
                                Nothing -> do modify (over lens (++[elem]))
                                              return . f $ length field
```

When I comment out the type signature for `updateRecord`, I get this error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Const [a] s’ with ‘Identity s’
      Expected type: ASetter s s [a] [a]
        Actual type: Getting [a] s [a]
```

Why is the type signature required in this case?

Comment: This question is actually similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203844/point-free-lens-creation-does-not-type-check?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `lens` is used in two contexts, `view lens`, where it is required to have type:

```
Getting [a] s [a]
= ([a] -> Const [a] [a]) -> (s -> Const [a] s)
```

and `over lens ...` where it is required to have type:

```
ASetter s s [a] [a]
= ([a] -> Identity [a]) -> (a -> Identity s)
```

Unfortunately, these types don't unify.  (In particular, the rightmost parts of these types, `Const [a] s` and `Identity s`, don't unify, which is what the error message is saying.)  When GHC tries to infer the type of `lens` in typechecking `updateRecord` without an explicit type signature, it infers the first type above for `lens` based on its use in `view` but then is unable to unify this with the second type that arises in `over`.

However, even though the types don't unify, there *is* a higher rank polymorphic type that can be specialized to each one separately, namely:

```
Lens' s a
= Lens s s a a = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f s) -> (a -> f s)
```

**As long as GHC can separately infer this type,** say by means of an explicit type signature, it's able to unify this more general type with each of the uses.

This is just one of those things, a fundamental limitation of higher rank types.  You can see the same phenomenon at work with a much smaller example.  This function `foo` doesn't typecheck:

```
foo f = (f 10, f "hello")
```

but add a type signature and it's fine:

```
foo :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (Int, String)
foo f = (f 10, f "hello")
```